# Last node is not being return when iterating from Xelement List using Linq to XML in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to get values from XML file using linq to XML, all nodes are being return expect the last one. for example here its sample data

```
<lista>
- <servizio>
  <idservizio>29</idservizio> 
  <idfascia>0</idfascia> 
  <nomeservizio>Shuttle service/ Taxi - Fiumicino Airport a Hotel</nomeservizio> 
- <descrizioneservizio>
- <![CDATA[ From Fiumicino (FCO) Airport to City Guest House Hotel. Up to 3 people.
  ]]> 
  </descrizioneservizio>
  <prezzoservizio>50.0</prezzoservizio> 
  <numerodisponibile>1000</numerodisponibile> 
  </servizio>
- <servizio>
  <idservizio>30</idservizio> 
  <idfascia>0</idfascia> 
  <nomeservizio>Shuttle service/ Taxi - Ciampino a Hotel</nomeservizio> 
- <descrizioneservizio>
- <![CDATA[ From Ciampino Airport to City Guest House Hotel. Price for up to 3 people.
  ]]> 
  </descrizioneservizio>
  <prezzoservizio>35.0</prezzoservizio> 
  <numerodisponibile>1000</numerodisponibile> 
  </servizio>
      </lista>
```

and its not returning  the node servizio with idservizio=30. Can anyone help me what i am doing wrong? Here below is my code

```
var ds1 = from XElement e in _resource.Descendants("lista")
                  select e;
        int eCnt = 0;
        foreach (XElement e in ds1)
        {
            XElement elm;

            elm = e.Elements("servizio").ElementAt(eCnt).Descendants("idservizio").FirstOrDefault();
            int idservice = elm != null ? elm.Value.ToInt32() : 0;

            if (idservice == 0) continue;

            //HH_dispService service = listService.SingleOrDefault(x => x.service_idservizio == idservice);

            HH_dispService service = new HH_dispService(idservice);

            elm = e.Elements("servizio").ElementAt(eCnt).Descendants("nomeservizio").FirstOrDefault();
            service.service_nomeservizio = elm != null ? elm.Value : "";

            elm = e.Elements("servizio").ElementAt(eCnt).Descendants("descrizioneservizio").FirstOrDefault();
            service.service_descrizioneservizio = elm != null ? elm.Value : "";

            elm = e.Elements("servizio").ElementAt(eCnt).Descendants("prezzoservizio").FirstOrDefault();
            service.service_prezzoservizio = elm != null ? elm.Value.Replace(".", ",").objToDecimal() : 0;
            listService.Add(service);

            eCnt++;
        }
```

Comment: Try using LinqPad and the .Dump() method. You'll find that you can easily visualize the structure/DOM of the XML allot easier using it. www.linqpad.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is currently looping over every `lista` element... but then using the index as a way of getting to a `servizio` element. That's a very odd way of going about things. It looks like you're also converting to `decimal` in an odd way.

Here's what I'd do:

```
foreach (var element in _resource.Descendants("lista").Elements("servizio"))
{
    // Consider *only* skipping if the element is missing, not
    // if it has a value of 0
    int id = (int?) element.Element("idservizio") ?? 0;
    if (id == 0)
    {
        continue;
    } 
    HH_dispService service = new HH_dispService(id);
    service.service_nomeservizio =
        (string) element.Element("nomeservizio") ?? "";
    service.service_descrizioneservizio = 
        (string) element.Element("descrizioneservizio") ?? "";
    service.service_prezzoservizio = 
        (decimal?) element.Element("prezzoservizio") ?? 0m;
    listService.Add(service);
}
```

(I'd also recommend changing your variable/property names... why would you want a prefix of `service_` on variables in a type which is inherently about a `service`?)

Comment: i gave a try but its not returning any values, actually its not able to find the node,FYI the XML i posted here its part of XML. its contains other nodes too

Comment: @TheCoder: Oh - well that would obviously affect things. Please be clearer next time. Will edit.

Comment: @ Jon its working now but again same problem that i stated for dasblinkenlight answer,after finishing iterate every nodes its again entering into the loop.

Comment: @TheCoder: Well that's presumably due to some of your *other* code - the loops *we* have provided won't do that. We can't tell what code you've got surrounding those loops though.

Answer (score 0):

That code is really weird.

You iterate over a list of `lista` but access the child node `servizio`. The result should be the first `servizio` node of the first `lista` node, the second `servizio` node of the second `lista` node and so on.

I would do it like this (assuming that `lista` is not the root tag):

```
var listaNodes = _resource.Descendants("lista");
foreach(var listaNode in listaNodes)
{
    foreach(var serviceNode in listaNode.Elements("servizio"))
    {
        var id = serviceNode.Element("idservizio");
        // ...
    }
}
```